# How to convert org.w3c.dom.Document to list of object?

Tags: java, android, xml

In my application i need to get some list of items from the server. 
I get this item list by sending http request and i get back some list of items that are set in xml.

In my code - i hold this xml in the object org.w3c.dom.Document - and now ,i want to convert this xml to simple list or ArrayList that will contain all those items.

My questions...

1. How can i do it ? How can i scan all the org.w3c.dom.Document and convert each of the items to be object ?
2. One of the items field is a image of the item - i get this image in byte array format. How can i convert it to simple image that i will be able to show on the android activity ( GUI ) ?

Thanks.